# unable to run npm typings install

Tags: node.js, mean-stack

I want to run an existing MEAN Stack Project. The steps I am following are first I am running `npm install` and then `npm run typings -- install` because I can't see any typings folder. But I am getting these errors.

```
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "run" "typings" "--" "install"
npm ERR! node v6.9.5
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10

npm ERR! missing script: typings
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/sami/projects/myappadmin/npm-debug.log
```

I am not sure how to get rid of this I spent a lot of time on google and tried different solutions but nothing worked for me.

My node version is `v6.9.5`. nodejs version is `v4.4.7`. MongoDB shell `version: 3.0.9`. npm `3.10.10`. nvm `0.31.1` ubuntu : `15.10`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue exists probably because you don't have "typings" script defined in your package.json. If you want to install typings, use

```
npm install typings -g
```

Comment: No, I have typings installed its version is 2.1.0

Comment: Good. Do you have typings.json file in the folder? Also check if you have typings script in packages.json.

Comment: Yes I had but I just ran typing -- install and it disappeared but now I can see the typings folder. but the issue now is that it gives me the same errors on npm start

Comment: When you are running some npm commands, you are actually running the scripts in your packages.json. If you want to install typing packages, the command you needs is typings install packagename assuming you have typings.json file. The typings folder is where your typings packages located. Check if there is any packages already installed.

Comment: yes angular protractor, corejs, jasmine, node and selenium webdriver inside the globals directory in typings.

Comment: It seems you have already installed typings packages. So in this case you should be good. What are you looking for now?

Comment: Now when I run 'npm start' command it gives me errors like previous. which should first compile the application, then simultaneously re-compiles and runs the lite-server.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137495/discussion-between-sami-and-zhangjinzhou).

Comment: Could you show me the "start" script in packages.json?

Answer (score 1):

why you are using typings use @types instead , read this article:

[@Types](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/typescript/2016/06/15/the-future-of-declaration-files/)

Comment: you want to take advantage of static typing of javascript libraries, for example expressJS so ` npm install @types/express ` and everything is done. with typings is too hard.